# Perimeter and area of a hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The floor of a theater was built in the shape of a hexagon. The interior angles of the hexagon are the same and one side is 8 meters long. How long is the perimeter of the floor in feet? 
What is the area of the floor in square yards?

Comment: Is the hexagon a regular one?

Comment: i have tried 48 for part a and 17 for part b

Comment: What Sigur meant was what work did you do.  Then we can see much better how to help.  Neither one will come out an exact integer.  Please note the change of units.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you must assume the hexagon is regular-otherwise you could have two opposite sides of any length.  You can divide a regular hexagon into six equilateral triangles.

Comment: how can i calculate the h for the triangle.

Comment: @SamiAlshehry It's an equilateral triangle. Drop a perpendicular from a vertex to the opposite side. Then use the Pythagorean theorem (the hypotenuse has length $8$ meters and the shorter side has length $4$ meters).